# How to set an environment variable to point to a location and how to set path of an environment variable in UBUNTU?

Tags: linux, path, dependencies, environment-variables, pardiso

I wish to have a particular environment variable `VAR1` ***point to a particular library*** named `lib123.so` which is placed in the home directory in a folder named `folder1`. I have performed this by typing in the command in terminal:

```
VAR1=/home/folder1/lib123.so
```

I also wish to have another environment variable VAR2 ***set to the path of the location*** of a file named `license.lic` which lies in the same folder `folder1`. I have performed this by doing the following in the terminal:

```
VAR1=/home/folder1
```

Are both the commands I have given above correct for the intended task? Is there any way in which I can check for myself if it has worked?

I have tried to explain my queries in a self-sufficient manner. However, if the context is important; I am trying to install the dependencies of a tool named PARDISO (page 31, 1st paragraph: https://pardiso-project.org/manual/manual.pdf).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the above command sets variable when executing together with other commands like so:

```
$ VAR1=/home/folder1/lib123.so MY_AWESOME_COMMAND
```

Or you can use `export` so that you won't have to include the variable in each command.

```
$ export VAR1=/home/folder1/lib123.so
```

Test it below:

```
$ echo $VAR1
$ /home/folder1/lib123.so
```